# Is it possible to see the Spark UI through EMR (through VPC)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark

I've gone through the process described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel-local.html to open an ssh tunnel through local-port forwarding, and then going to http://localhost:8157/.

This brings up the Hadoop/YARN interface, at which point I click on the Tracking UI/ApplicationMaster link, and receive a "This site's server DNS could not be found" page.

According to the AWS docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-history.html that should bring me to the Spark UI.

Is there another step I'm missing to be able to see the Spark UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best experience comes from using a SOCKS proxy through SSH so that it can dynamically support the URLs and ports.  Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-ssh-tunnel.html.

Comment: What is the url you are supposed to go to once you have the SOCKS proxy open?  That's what I can't seem to find.

Comment: After enabling SOCKS return to the EMR console, select the cluster and at top if the proxy is setup you will see hyperlinks to Resource Manager from where selecting the Application URL will then redirect properly to the Spark UI for a Spark app.